# Enabling optimisation causes permission problems

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clang

I have a C++ project building using cmake in Windows 10 (Visual Studio 2019, though it's only using the build tools for that rather than the GUI and the actual compiler being used is clang). It builds fine if I build it without compiler optimisation, but if I pass `-O3` through using `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")` then the compiled binaries have some sort of permissions problem. ctest refuses to run the tests with an "operation not permitted" message, and if I go find the test binary to run it manually that gives me a permission denied error.

There's nothing obviously wrong with the permissions in Windows (Execute permissions are there) and it isn't a caching problem because it reoccurs if I delete the build tree and start from scratch. It might conceivably be related to Boost (which is being linked into the test binaries as well as the main executable) but that's mostly me grasping at straws.

Anyone know why enabling optimisation would cause a permissions problem?

Comment: Isn't permission problem one possible/frequent output of buffer overflow/wrong memory access  (or other undefined behaviour in general). As Debug tends to initialize memory page to zero, issue is more visible in release builds.

Comment: When you add the optimization option to the variable, you should also include the options previously set by CMake, e.g. do a  `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O3")`

Comment: It’s not building fine. It is probably throwing warnings that you’re ignoring. Increase your warning level, fix all your warnings, and run the program through asan and ubsan and your program will work.

Comment: What is the message?

Comment: In general if optimizations lead to errors, I'm thinking of undefined behaviour in the code. Check that problem is actually what you think it is. Maybe the program is failing with a access violation.

Comment: Voting to close for non-reproducibility, but I'm happy you solved your problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

In presumably-not-a-coincidence, our IT department just contacted me to ask why our build machine is tripping their antivirus alerts. Some of my built-with-optimisation files (specifically, the test executables that are refusing to run) apparently look like some sort of adware (they definitely are not, they aren't for use by the general public so that'd be pointless even if I was evil).

So I'm guessing the reason they won't run is that they've scared our antivirus. Would've been nice if I'd had a better error message!